# Android, something won't work in onCreate(), but it will in onResume()

Tags: android

I have an Android app which changes the ringer volume to maximum and restores the volume upon exit or home button pressed. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
int ringMode;
int ringVolume;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    changeRingtone();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    changeRingtone();
}

private void changeRingtone() {
    ringVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_RING);
    ringMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_RING,
         audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioManager.STREAM_RING),
         AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_RING, ringVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(ringMode);
        super.onPause();
}
```

Now the issue is, when the app first launches (`onCreate()` is called), it changes the volume to max, but it doesn't restore it to previous volume in `onPause()`. However, if the app is started by `onResume()` (means the app was in background), it will change the volume to max and it does restore it to previous volume in `onPause()`.

The code seems to be fine but I haven't figured out where is the problem for several days, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to life cycle of Android `Activity`, you are calling to `changeRingtone()` method twice, you should call this method only in your `onResume` method.

[image: Activity life cycle]

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) article from the official Android training:

> By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save
>   information about each View object in your activity layout (such as
>   the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity
>   instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is
>   restored to its previous state with no code required by you. However,
>   your activity might have more state information that you'd like to
>   restore, such as member variables that track the user's progress in
>   the activity.

For further explanations, check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state) StackOverFlow post.

Answer (score 0):

on Pause  will call when after your activity launched and in between a phone call comes.